# Equation with absolute value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried to solve my first equation with absolute value:

$$ |x+1 | < 0.01 $$

if $ x < (-1) $ then $x+1$ is negative, so $|x+1|  =  -(x+1)$ :

$ -x-1 < 0.01 $

$ -x < 0.01 + 1 $

$ -x < 1.01 $

$ x > -1.01 $

$ -1.01 < x < -1 $

if $ x > -1 $  then $ x + 1 $ is positive, so $ |x+1| = x+1 $

$ x + 1 < 0.01 $

$ x < -1.01 $

in this stage I don't know what to do.
There is $ x < -1.01 $ and $ x > -1 $ , how can I combine them?
or maybe I did a mistake?

Comment: $|x-(-1)|<0.01$ means $x\in(-1.01,-0.99)$. Think of it in terms of the number line. The distance between $x$ and $-1$ is less than $0.01$.

Comment: Your very last step is wrong. $x + 1 < 0.01$ implies $x < -0.99$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful; we have $0.01 - 1 = -0.99$.

A string of symbols involving $<$ or $>$ or $\leq$ or $\geq$ is called an inequality.

The problem is not that complicated; note that $|x+1| < 0.01$ iff $-0.01 < x+1 < 0.01$ and iff $-1.01 < x < -0.99$.

Answer (score 3):

$$|x+1|<0.01$$
or, $$-0.01<x+1<0.01$$
or, $$-1.01<x<-0.99$$

**Edit:** Canceled the +1 in last step.

Comment: You may want to change that last $x+1$ to an $x$.